# How to host wordpress site on mian domain and rails site a subdomain

Tags: ruby-on-rails, wordpress, heroku, subdomain

I currently have a wordpress site that is hosted with wpengine at mydomain.com.  The current wordpress site is a crowdfunding platform but now we are adding in a grants component. I would like to keep the crowdfunding fully functional but then also host the grants features at grants.wpengine.com using rails on heroku. Eventually I plan on merging the crowdfunding into the rails grants app but in the meantime I want both co-exist.  Is this even possible and how would I go about doing so?  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've built setups like this before, and typically what I've done is this:

Setup hosting for the wordpress website on Heroku or another service provider, and point your main domain to that IP address via an A Record.

Setup your Heroku Rails app on Heroku, they assign you a `*.herokuapp.com` domain.  Create an A record for your subdomain, and point it to `*.herokuapp.com`.

You now have your website functioning on one host and your Rails app on a sub domain running on Heroku.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.  To be more specific for future users my wordpress site was already set up so I left it's setup alone.  I use namecheap.com btw.  I went to the domian list, clicked on my domain, then advanced DSN.  I added a new CNAME Record as type, host was grants and value was *.herokuapp.com.    The last thing I did was put this in terminal: heroku domains:add grants.mydomain.com